# Jersey Security annotations ignored on grizzly work fine on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly

Been stuck on a problem for a while now and searched every possible post but can't find why jersey is ignoring my security annotation?

Basically my Resource Config looks like so

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class ApplicationResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationResourceConfig()
    {
        packages("com.property");
        register(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener.class);
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class);
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringLifecycleListener.class);
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.ValidationFeature.class);
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class); 
    }
}
```

My Secuirity Context is defined as so;

```
@Provider   
public class Authorizer implements javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext {

    private final Account account;
    private final Session session;
    private final Principal principal;

    public Authorizer() {
        super();
        this.account = null;
        this.session = null;
        this.principal = null;
    }

    public Authorizer(Account account, Session session) {
        this.account = account;
        this.session = session;

        this.principal = new Principal() {

           public String getName() {
               return account.getAlias();
           }
       };
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return Authorizer.BASIC_AUTH;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        //return "https".equals(uriInfo.get().getRequestUri().getScheme());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {

        if ((role == null) || (session == null) || (!session.isValidSession()) || (this.session.getType() == null) || (account == null)) 
            return false;

        return this.session.getType().toString().equals(role);
    }

}
```

Security Filter looks like so

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    javax.inject.Provider<UriInfo> uriInfo;

    @Autowired
    private HibernateSessionFacotry sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        try
        {
            String sessionKey = request.getHeaderString("Authorization");
            Integer uid = request.getHeaderString("From") == null  ? null : Integer.parseInt(request.getHeaderString("From"));

            if ((sessionKey == null) || (uid == null))
                return;

            Session session = null;
            Account account = null;

            session = sessionFactory.getSessionDAO().verifySession(uid, sessionKey);
            if (session != null)
                account = session.getAccount();

            if  (
                    (session != null) 
                    && (account != null)
                    && (session.getSessionKey().equals(sessionKey)) 
                    && (session.getAccountId() == uid)
                    && (session.isValidSession())
                )
                    request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer(account, session));
            else
                request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO:: ONLY PRINT IN DEBUG MODE
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My Resources

```
@Path("/account")
public class AccountImpl implements Account{

    @POST
    @DenyAll
    @Audit
    @NotNull @ValidAccount
    public com.property.db.entities.account.Account createAccount
    (
        @NotNull @ValidPostAccount final com.property.db.entities.account.Account account,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request
    ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, MandrillApiError, IOException;

}
```

But for some reason the security annotation @DenyAll gets ignored and I get a 200 response. Any reason why this is happening as I am completely baffled right now.

EDIT::

Just noticed that the security annotation are only ignored from my grizzly servlet any idea why this is happening?

```
public class WebTest extends JerseyTest {

    protected static SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
    protected static GensonProvider gesonProvider = null;
    protected static HibernateSessionFacotry sessionFactory = null;

    @Override 
    protected Application configure() { 
            enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC); 
            enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

            return new ApplicationResourceConfig(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new TestContainerFactory() {
            @Override

            public TestContainer create(final URI baseUri, ApplicationHandler application) 
                throws IllegalArgumentException {
                return new TestContainer() {
                    private HttpServer server;

                    @Override
                    public ClientConfig getClientConfig() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public URI getBaseUri() {
                        return baseUri;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void start() {
                        try {
                            this.server = 
                                GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri);

                            WebappContext context = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "");

                            context.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
                            context.addListener(org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.class);

                            ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet("ServletContainer", org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class);
                            registration.addMapping("/*");
                            registration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.property.filters.auditing;com.property.filters.security;com.property.filters.versioning;com.property.resources");
                            registration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace", "true");


                            context.deploy(server);                         
                        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
                            throw new TestContainerException(e);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new TestContainerException(e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void stop() {
                        this.server.stop();
                    }
                };

            }


        };
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        assertNotNull(sdf);

        gesonProvider = new GensonProvider();
        assertNotNull(gesonProvider);

        sessionFactory = new HibernateSessionFacotry();
        assertNotNull(sessionFactory);
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the ContainerRequestFilter filter is succesfully invoked and the Security Context is created  as when i modify the resource to include @Context SecurityContext sc is succesfully populated and isUserInRole return the correct value.

The problem seems that security annotation such as DenyAll are ignored

Comment: Just Edited the question the security annotation are only ignored in grizzly. On tomcat they work fine. But i still need them to work on grizzly since i use it as my testing framework

Comment: Try to register also your `SecurityFilter` in `ApplicationResourceConfig`. And are you sure your filter is invoked. And using the same example on real servlet container works good?